# Angular 7 component testing - how to verify input element value

Tags: angular, testing, angular-ngmodel, html-input

I upgraded an existing working application from Angular 4 to Angular 7.

For an HTML Input such as follows:

```
<input id="encryptedValue" readonly class="form-control" [ngModel]="Response.encryptedText" size="50" />
```

Before the upgrade, I can verify an Input element contains desired value by doing:

```
  const de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#encryptedValue'));
  const el = de.nativeElement;
  expect(el.value).toBe(dummyStr);
```

After the upgrade, el.value is `''` instead of `'Test'`

If I do a `console.log(el)`, the following is string is displayed:

```
<input _ngcontent-c0="" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="encryptedValue" readonly="" size="50" ng-reflect-model="Test">
```

It seems the value 'Test' is now from the attribute ng-reflect-model. I can do verify the attribute value by doing:

```
expect(el.getAttribute('ng-reflect-model')).toBe('Test');
```

But is this the correct way of verifying the value of an element in the component view?

Answer (score 2):

el.value looks right. Try:

```
fixture.detectChanges();
fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
  expect(el.value).toBe(dummyVal)
})
```